# UIBezierPath from image

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-processing, uiimage, uibezierpath

I have several png files that look similar to this this:

[image]

Everything is transparent but the black path. What I am trying to do is create a UIBezierPath from the non transparent part.

Edit:
So I was thinking what about creating a mask with the png then from the mask go to a UIBezierPath. Would that work?

Edit Again:
I found the solution, look at my answer.

Comment: yikes.  this is a hard problem -  more like a science project than a coding question  1) need to extract points from the image, 2) need to fit a bezier to the data.  Check out http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/ios/image_manipulation/image_manipulation.html for feature extraction, and http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/Bezier/bezier-construct.html for Bezier derivation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I went a different direction. Instead of using PNGs I went with SVG and used [PocketSVG](https://github.com/arielelkin/PocketSVG) to parse the file. It works great.

Comment: Good choice. You could also create your own, optimized file format if that is required, as well.

Answer (score 1):

The process you're looking for is known as skeletonization, there's a good summary of techniques in this post:
[Determine the midline of a bent, elongated region](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555682/determine-the-midline-of-a-bent-elongated-region)

Comment: Thanks for the input, I went a different direction and it works great.